# @Cachebale not working with Ehcache and spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

`@Cacheble` is not working . I am using ehcache in Spring MVC Project.My service is acting as a DAO .Using Spring 4 and ehcache 2.10 version. Please see the implementation below

app-ctx.xml -- Application Context xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd        
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <cache:annotation-driven />  
 <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

Please see the ehcache.xml below

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" 
    updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" 
    dynamicConfig="true">

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />

    <cache name="timeTrackerDashBoardCountCache" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="100"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
        eternal="false" 
        timeToIdleSeconds="300" 
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" 
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Please see   Service class `TelleCallerDashboardService.java` below

```
@Service
public class TelleCallerDashboardService extends BaseNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {

 @Cacheable(value = "timeTrackerDashBoardCountCache", key="#league")
    public void timeTrackerDashBoardCount(final TelleCallerDashboardDTO telleCallerDashboardDTO) {

}
```

Please advice

Comment: What should be cached with a `void` method? Also your `@Cacheable` doesn't make sense with the method you are invoking.

Comment: You need to have return type and key should name of input parameter i.e. telleCallerDashboardDTO and you are missing @CacheConfig

Comment: The method timeTrackerDahshBoardCount does not return anything, the object telleCallerDashboardDTO  is passed from the calling method, it uses object telleCallerDashboardDTO to store the values from database. The calling method gets the updated value. I will test the code with  return value and key=telleCallerDashboardDTO. And add @CacheConfig  ... Thank you

Comment: Hi I modified                                                     @CacheConfig(cacheNames = "TelleCallerDashboard")
public class TelleCallerDashboardService extends BaseNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {     @Cacheable(value = "timeTrackerDashBoardCountCache", key="telleCallerDashboardDTO")
    public TelleCallerDashboardDTO timeTrackerDashBoardCount(final TelleCallerDashboardDTO telleCallerDashboardDTO) {
        System.out.println("********** Inside timeTrackerDashBoardCountCache at " + DateUtility.dateToStringWithTime(new Date()));

Comment: @M. Deinum please suggest

Comment: @yogi please suggest

Answer (score 0):

***@Cacheable*** is used to demarcate methods that are cacheable - that is, methods for whom the result is stored into the cache so on subsequent invocations (with the same arguments), the value in the cache is returned without having to actually execute the method.

Since your method returns nothing as it is marked as void.
Nothing will put in cache.

If you want to use @Cacheable or @CachePut, you need to return something with method annotated with caching annotations.

For working code:

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "TelleCallerDashboard") 
public class TelleCallerDashboardService extends BaseNamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport {

 @Cacheable(value = "timeTrackerDashBoardCountCache", key="#telleCallerDashboardDTO")
    public AnyReturnClass timeTrackerDashBoardCount(final TelleCallerDashboardDTO telleCallerDashboardDTO) {

        return anyReturnClassObject;
    }

}
```

For further reading:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html
- https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks